# Problems with common mode expansion for 2D plane CFT for non integer weight?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

Equation (6.7) in the big yellow book [(Di Francesco, Mathieu, Senechal)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9) says we can write the field of a 2D CFT with weight $(h, \bar h) = (\tfrac{1}{2}(\Delta + J), \tfrac{1}{2}(\Delta - J))$ as

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\phi(z, \bar{z} ) = \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z} } \frac{\phi_{m,n}}{z^{m + h} \bar{z}^{n + \bar{h} } }
\end{equation}
I am very confused for this equation due to the appearance of $(m + h)$ and $(n + h)$ in the denominator instead of $m$ and $n$ (where $m$ and $n$ are integers). Note that while $h - \bar{h} = J$ is an integer, $h$ and $\bar{h}$ do not have to be integers individually, which is what confuses me.

I have read [this answer which motivates it from a cylinder CFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/566357), but I don't want an answer that references the cylinder, I am interested in a resolution involving only the plane.

I will list my problems with this equation:

1. Wouldn't a more standard expression be
   \begin{equation} \tag{2}
   \phi(z, \bar{z} ) = \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z} } \frac{\phi_{m,n}}{z^{m} \bar{z}^{n} }
   \end{equation}
   which is basically a Laurant expansion? For example, if $\phi(z, \bar{z})$ were just a function (I know it's really an operator) then a very large class of functions can be written in terms of the equation above, as essentially a Laurent series, but I don't know what class of functions can be written with $m + h$ and $n + \bar{h}$ instead of $m$ and $n$?
   It seems to me that if a function is expressible in terms of equation $(1)$, it can't be expressible in terms of equation $(2)$, and vice versa. In other words, only one can be correct and the other must be wrong, It can't be a matter of convention. I would like an explanation as to why $(1)$ must be correct and $(2)$ must be incorrect (without invoking the cylinder), especially given that a Laurent series seems to me to be more natural.
2. If $m$ and $n$ are too big, the operator $\phi_{m, n}$ will annihilate the vacuum state $|0\rangle$. This is because the correlation functions must be smoothly varying as $z \to 0$.
   \begin{equation} \tag{3}
   \phi_{m,n} |0\rangle = 0 \text{ for } (m,n) > (-h, -\bar{h})
   \end{equation}
   However... doesn't that imply that all states made from acting on the vacuum are $0$, just because all the powers of $z$ that remain are positive?
   \begin{equation} \tag{4}
   \phi(0,0) | 0 \rangle = \lim_{z, \bar{z} \to 0} \sum_{(m,n) > (-h, -\bar{h}) } \frac{\phi_{m,n}}{z^{m + h} \bar{z}^{n + \bar{h} } } |0 \rangle =0
   \end{equation}
   If $h$ was an integer, then one power would remain that is $z^0$, but I'm assuming $h$ isn't an integer.

Comment: If you don't want an answer to reference the cylinder, then the only correct answer to your question is "it's a convention".

Comment: Another possible answer to your question is that we would like to choose notation so that $\phi_{m,n} \ket{0}$ for all $m,n>0$.

Comment: @user1379857 why you don't want an answer that references the cylinder?

Comment: If $h$ (or ${\bar h}$) is half-integer, then the field $\phi(z,{\bar z})$ is not single-valued on the plane and this is crucial (rotation by $2\pi$ on the cylinder is not the identity for fermionic states). This multi-valuedness is clearly absent in your (2), but is there in (1).

Comment: I'm skeptical that it is even a matter of convention. The analyticity properties seem different to me depending on whether one uses (1) or (2). I suspect only one can be correct. I am also interested in $h \in \mathbb{R}$, not necessarily a half integer. $h$ doesn't have to be rational.

Comment: @user1379857 If you are interested in $h \in {\mathbb R}$ you need to understand what that means. It means that your field has particular properties as you rotate $z \to e^{2\pi i} z$. In particular, for generic $h \in {\mathbb R}$, the field is multi-valued. All of these properties are captured by the expansion (1), but not (2).

Comment: If we use (1), then assuming it's not multivalued under $z \mapsto e^{2 \pi i } z$ we get  $h - \bar{h} \in \mathbb{Z}$. However individually both $h, \bar{h}$ can be real

Comment: I am taking $z \to e^{2\pi i} z$ and ${\bar z} \to {\bar z}$.

Comment: I am puzzled by your point 2. Say $h=1$, then the terms proportional to $z^{-1}$, $z^{-2}$, $\ldots$ do not annihilate the vacuum. I don't see why you say only the $z^{0}$ term remains

Comment: Because the terms corresponding to $z^{-N}$ for $N > 0$ are attatched to operators which annihilate the vacuum, and the terms $z^{N}$ for $N > 0$ go away do to $ z \to 0$.

Comment: $z \mapsto e^{i \theta} z$ and $\bar {z} \mapsto z$ isn't real transformation so I don't see how you need to stipulate you return to your starting point for $\theta = 2 \pi$. Let me note that $h \in \mathbb{R}$ isn't such a strange condition, for instance in string theory with the constant mode you can have $h = \bar{h} = \alpha k^2 / 4$. The condition $h - \bar{h} \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a common one

Comment: @user1379857 - I don't see why it would matter that the transformation isn't real? In 2D CFT, we analytically continue $z$ and ${\bar z}$ to be INDEPENDENT complex coordinates. Such analytic continuations are quite necessary to define CFTs and to perform calculations. At the end of the computation, we then reduce to the real slice $z^* = {\bar z}$. It is perfectly acceptable (and important when one studies CFTs) to consider transformations like $z \to e^{2\pi i} z$ and ${\bar z} \to {\bar z}$.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you can't have $h, \bar{h} \in \mathbb{R}$? Because I'm sure you can (like in free boson cft)

Comment: @user1379857 - I am NOT saying that. I am simply saying that when $h \in {\mathbb R}$, the field is not single valued as $z \to e^{2\pi i}z$, ${\bar z} \to {\bar z}$ and this multi-valuedness is reflected in the expansion (1), but not in (2). Therefore (1) is correct and (2) is not.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. But doesn't that contradict the claim that whether you use (1) or (2) is a matter of convention?

Comment: @user1379857 - yes, "it's a convention" was a naive answer (though correct to some extent since the multivaluedness could potentially have been absorbed into a crazy transformation of $\phi_{m,n}$). The better answer is given by the multi-valuedness argument AND my second comment regarding the action of $\phi_{m,n}$ on the vacuum state.

Comment: i think the relevant case might be when $\phi(z,\bar{z})$ are 'components' of a tensor in a given chart, in the sense that the conformally-invariant quantity in that chart is: $\phi(z,\bar{z})(dz)^h(d\bar{z})^{\tilde{h}}$. With the Laurent expansion of $\phi(z,\bar{z})$ as in (1), the modes scale in a convenient way under $z\rightarrow \lambda z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bw}{{\bar{w}}} \newcommand{\bh}{{\bar{h}}} \newcommand{\mO}{\mathcal{O}} \newcommand{\vk}{|0\rangle} \newcommand{vb}{\langle 0|}$

Okay, here is the answer. Here we use
\begin{align}
h &= \tfrac{1}{2}( \Delta + J) \\
\bar{h} &= \tfrac{1}{2}( \Delta - J) 
\end{align}
where $\Delta > 0$ and $J \in \mathbb{Z}$.

### Plane

On the Euclidean plane we have the mode expansion
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{O}^{(p)}(w, \bw) = \sum_{m,n = 0}^\infty (a^\dagger_{mn} w^{m} \bw^n + a_{mn} w^{-m-2h} \bw^{-n-2\bh}).
\end{equation}
With the adjoint given by
\begin{equation}
    [\mO^{(p)}(w, \bw) ]^\dagger = \bw^{-2\bh} w^{-2 h} \mO^{(p)}(1/\bw, 1/w)
\end{equation}
we then have
\begin{equation}
    [\mO^{(p)}(w, \bw) ]^\dagger = \sum_{m,n = 0}^\infty (a_{mn} \bw^{m}w^n + a_{mn}^\dagger \bw^{-m-2h} w^{-n-2\bh})
\end{equation}
which you can see by inspection is indeed the adjoint of $\mathcal{O}^{(p)}$ we have written.

If we also have
\begin{align}
    a_{mn} \vk &= 0 \\
    \vb a_{mn}^\dagger &= 0
\end{align}
then this implies
\begin{align}
    \mO^{(p)}(0,0) \vk &= a^\dagger_{00} \vk \\
    \vb [\mO^{(p)}(0,0)]^\dagger &= \vb a_{00} \\
    \vb [\mO^{(p)}(0,0)]^\dagger \mO^{(p)}(0,0) \vb &= \vb a_{00} a_{00}^\dagger \vk.
\end{align}

### Cylinder

Let's now transform to the Euclidean cylinder. We have ($\sigma \sim \sigma + 2 \pi$)
\begin{align}
    w &= e^{w'} = e^{\tau + i \sigma} \\
    w' &= \ln(w)
\end{align}
and the primary transformation law
\begin{equation}
    \mO'(w', \bw') = (\partial_w w')^{-h} (\partial_\bw \bw')^{-\bh} \mO(w, \bw).
\end{equation}
This means that
\begin{align}
    \mO^{(c)}(\tau, \sigma) &= w^h \bw^\bh\mO^{(p)} (w, \bw)
\end{align}
Using
\begin{align}
    w^h \bw^\bh &= (e^{\tau + i \sigma})^h (e^{\tau - i \sigma})^\bh \\
    &= e^{\tau(h + \bh) + i \sigma ( h - \bh)} \\
    &= e^{\tau\Delta + i \sigma J}
\end{align}
we get
\begin{align}
    \mO^{(c)}(\tau, \sigma) &= \sum_{m,n = 0}^\infty ( a^\dagger_{mn} e^{(m + n + \Delta) \tau + i (m-n + J) \sigma} + a_{mn} e^{-(m+n + \Delta ) \tau - i (m -n + J) \sigma} ).
\end{align}
Note that, in Euclidean signature, we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{O}^{(c)}(\tau, \sigma) = e^{\tau H} \mO(0, \sigma)^{(c)} e^{- \tau H}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
    [\mathcal{O}^{(c)}(\tau, \sigma)]^\dagger &=
    e^{-\tau H} [\mO^{(c)}(0, \sigma)]^\dagger e^{ \tau H} \\
    &= \mO^{(c)}(- \tau, \sigma).
\end{align}
Here we used that the operator is self adjoint on the $t = \tau = 0$ time slice. The above equation is different from Lorentzian signature, where the adjoint fixes $t \mapsto t$, because the lack of an $i$ now means that $\tau \mapsto - \tau$. In any case, we can see by inspection that our expression for $\mathcal{O}^{(c)}$ does indeed satisfy the above relationship.

Now, let's see how to act with this operator at the distant past. We then have
\begin{align}
    \lim_{\tau \to - \infty} \mO^{(p)}(w, \bw) \vk &= \lim_{\tau \to - \infty} w^{-h} \bw^{-\bh} \mO^{(c)}( \tau, \sigma) \vk \\
    &=\lim_{\tau \to - \infty} (e^{-\Delta \tau - i J \sigma})e^{\Delta \tau + i J \sigma} a_{00}^\dagger \vk \\
    &=a_{00}^\dagger \vk.
\end{align}
We have to put in the prefactor $w^{-h} \bw^{-\bh}$, otherwise the euclidean time evolution will decay away the state to zero because $\Delta > 0$. However, this is precisely the factor you would expect to get just from the relationship of $\mO^{(p)}$ and $\mO^{(c)}$.